# How do I fill the entire background color of a margin?

Tags: html, css

I can't do padding because I need a negative layout so it can be smaller than padding size 1. And Margin allows me to go negative which is what I need but I can't seem to fill out the background color of it completely. Are there better alternatives to a negative margin that can completely fill the background color of its chosen size?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

  <head>
    <title>CSS Challenge 3</title>
  </head>

  <style>

  html{
  background-color: #518c6b;

  }

    body{
    position: absolute;
    right: 320px;
  }

    #nav{
    margin:-10px;
    padding:1px;

    }

    #nav li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 24px;
    }

  #numbers{
    width: 150px;
    height: 490px; /*This is what determines the height of the line (the length */
    float: right;
    padding:10px;
    border-top: 3px dashed #ffffff;


  margin-left:24px;
  background-color:#92AD4E;

  }
  #content{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 3px dashed #ffffff;

  }

  .copyright{


  background-color: #66CDAA;
   margin-left:-16px;
   margin-right:-1px;

   clear: both;

  }

  ul.noBullets{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;

  }

  #yolo{
   background-color:#7c915b;
   height: 509px;
   padding:1px;
   text-align: justify;
   padding-left:15px;

  }

  #header{
    background-color: #92AD4E;
    height: 90px;
    padding-top: 1px;


  }

  #wrap{

    width: 700px;
    height: 9px;

    }

   a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

  .tab{
    margin-left: 40px;
    }

   #pos{
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding-left: 450px;
  }

  #titlePos{
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;

  }

  #headPos{
  padding-top: 5px;
  }

  #underline{
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  #sonnetIndex{
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    font-size:18px; 
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  </style>

  <body>
  <div id="wrap">

      <div id="header">
        <h1 id="pos">Shakespear.net</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sonnets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Life Story</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Shakespear.net</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>




              <div id="numbers">

                <h2 id="sonnetIndex">Sonnet Index</h2>
                    <ul id="underline">
                          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #6</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #11</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #15</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Sonnet #18</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>

      <div id="content">
        <div id="yolo">
           <h1 id="titlePos">Shakespeare's Sonnet #18</h1>
                <p id="headPos">This is one of the most famous of the sonnets. It is referenced
                   in the film Dead Poets Society and gave names to the band The
                   Darling Buds and the book and television series The Darling Buds
                   of May. Read it and weep!</p>
                        <ul class="noBullets">
                          <li>Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?</li>
                          <li>Thou art more lovely and more temperate:</li>
                          <li>Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,</li>
                          <li>And summer's lease hath all too short a date:</li>
                          <li>Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,</li>
                          <li>And often is his gold complexion dimm'd,</li>
                          <li>And every fair from fair sometime declines,</li>
                          <li>By chance, or nature's changing course<br> untrimm'd:</br></li>
                          <li>But thy eternal summer shall not fade,</li>
                          <li>Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow'st,</li>
                          <li>Nor shall death brag thou wander'st in his shade,</li>
                          <li>When in eternal lines to time thou grow'st,</li>
                          <li>So long as men can breathe, or eyes can see,</li>
                          <li>So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.</li>
                        </ul>

                <p class="copyright">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;See the 
                <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare%27s_Sonnets">
                Shakespeare's sonnets</a> Wikipedia article for more information
                </p>

            </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see some code, what you have done so far, how it is not looking the way you like and what do you want it to look like.

Comment: To fill the background of the margin, there is no choice but to use the parent to fill the background of. Your other question is a bit unclear: negative margins don't have backgrounds.